# How can I get RET to follow org-mode links when using evil-mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, evil, keymap

In `org-mode`, the link-following behaviour of `RET`, that should be present when `org-return-follows-link` is set, doesn't work in `evil-mode`.

MWE from `emacs -q`:

1. Load an org buffer containing a link. Note that `RET` is bound to `org-ret`, but doesn't follow links. [Expected]
2. Set `org-return-follows-link`.  Hit `RET` when point is over a link. Emacs follows the link. [Expected]
3. Enable `evil-mode`. Note that `RET` is now bound to `evil-ret`, and no longer follows links. [Not what I expected]

It makes no difference if `evil-mode` is enabled before or after we enter `org-mode` or set `org-return-follows-link`.

I also tried it with `evil-org-mode` from https://github.com/Somelauw/evil-org-mode, but that didn't make any difference either. I did notice some code in there that seems to optionally customise the behaviour of the return key according to a "keymap theme", but I didn't seem to be able to make any difference either by playing with that.

So, any idea how I can follow links in `org-mode` with `evil-mode` enabled, using `RET`? I suppose one option is just to override the mapping of `RET` to be `org-ret`, but I get the feeling that that will interfere with other uses of the key that evil relies on. Is there a smarter way that these two behaviours should be integrated?

Thanks.

Comment: unbinding RET makes RET, when in normal mode and the point is not on a link, to insert a new line, which is very unexpected. it seems that binding RET to the code below seems to render a more as expected behavior. But I'm not really sure. Anyone suggesting a different approach? (defun foo () (interactive) (if (string= (car (org-thing-at-point)) "link") (org-return) (evil-ret)))

Answer (score 7):

The easy way out is to unbind `RET` for Evil as it isn't bound to a useful command anyway. This will let Emacs look it up in keymaps with less priority. You can do the same with `SPC` and `TAB` (keep in mind that this is the same as `C-i`, so maybe not). The following is lifted from my personal setup:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "RET") nil)
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "TAB") nil))
```